# Best suitable Timer for correct measurement of cache access time

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, performance-testing

There exist so many timers which can be used to find time taken to execute a task or a program takes to complete its execution for example.

I would like to find the access time of L2 cache set by set by accessing array elements loaded into cache . To find the access time of all sets of L2 cache set by set time calculation , I have tried different options like - **rdtsc(), gettimeofday ()**, but not getting exact result as expected .

**I am using intel i7 machine in linux with gcc 4.8.** What is the best timer to calculate the cache access time with more accuracy.

my approach is as follow

```
for ( j=0; j<100000;j++
{

for ( set_no = 0 ; set_no< 4096; set_no ++)
{ 

start= rdtsc()
{
access all blocks of a set = set_no;
}
end = rdtsc()


time_taken[set_no]+= end -start ;
}
}

for(set_no=0;set_no<4096;set_no++)
printf(" time needed for access set %d = %llu", set_no, time_taken[set_no]/100000);
```

I would like to know whether BEST/SUITABLE Timer available in C or C++ ?

**I need to prevent out-of_order execution in i3/i7 to get correct time measurement, so** **SERIALIZATION of timer is required.** Which timer should I use to get correct result with SERIALIZED OUTPUT. rdtsc() has OPTION to serialized the timer output, DOES other timer also have the same ?

should I use other option to calculate time to get better result ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since your compiler is capable of C++11, I'd go with std::chrono::high_resolution_clock.
For http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock tells:

> Class std::chrono::high_resolution_clock represents the clock with the smallest tick period provided by the implementation.

Comment: `high_resolution_clock` has a low resolution in Visual Studio, use `steady_clock` instead >.<